# Javascript client generates transaction that is not found on etherchain

Tags: go-ethereum, console, cli

I'm having a tough time. I am trying to do a simple sendTransaction from the javascript console. I get a transaction id but it is invalid (or not found) on etherchain.org. I've already tried re-installing the console and reloading the database. Any help would be SOOO appreciated. Thanks!

This is an example of the command i'm using:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.coinbase, to: '0xa8ade7feab1ece71446bed25fa0cf6745c19c3d5', value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})
```

Comment: I will be helpful to show the command you're using to progress through this. You can edit the question to provide more details.